# How to print 5 lines before and after the match regex with awk command

Tags: bash, awk

I want to use awk to print 5 lines before and 5 lines after the match regex (Start in ERROR and finish with on of INFO |WARN |DEBUG|TRACE).
Also, I need to print the line number as well.
I just success to print the line number

```
cat  foo |  awk '/\[ERROR\]/,/\[(INFO |WARN |DEBUG|TRACE)/{print NR":"$0}'
```

I don't care to find a solution with grep command

For example, the file contains:

```
DEBUG
DEBUG
DEBUG
TRACE
TRACE
INFO 
INFO 
ERROR
INFO 
INFO 
INFO 
DEBUG
DEBUG
DEBUG
DEBUG
```

The output should be:

```
3: DEBUG
4: TRACE
5: TRACE
6: INFO 
7: INFO 
**8: ERROR
9: INFO** 
10: INFO 
11: INFO 
12: DEBUG
13: DEBUG
14: DEBUG
```

The stars mark the match regex(Begin in ERROR, end in INFO)

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment)

Comment: `grep -n -A5 -B5 ERROR file.txt`

Comment: `grep -n -A5 -B5 ERROR file.txt | sed 's/:/: /;s/-/: /'`

Comment: will you always have at least 5 lines before/after the start pattern ('ERROR' in this example)?  can you have more than one 'ERROR' in the file? what would you expect as output if there are 2x 'ERROR' patterns and less than 10 lines between them?

Answer (score 3):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ buf[NR%6] = $0 }
/ERROR/ { tgt=NR; f=1 }
tgt == NR {
    for (i=1; i<=6; i++) {
        print (NR+i-6) ":", buf[(NR+i)%6]
    }
}
f && /INFO|WARN|DEBUG|TRACE/ { tgt=NR+5; f=0 }
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
3: DEBUG
4: TRACE
5: TRACE
6: INFO
7: INFO
8: ERROR
9: INFO
10: INFO
11: INFO
12: DEBUG
13: DEBUG
14: DEBUG
```

Answer (score 0):

I submit this awk for peer reviewing, turned my brain to  a bowl of spagetti (can't even spell *spaghetti* correctly):

```
$ awk '{
    $0=NR " " $0                     # prepend NR to record
}
!f {
    b[6]=$0                          # buffer to hold 5 previous lines
    for(i=1;i<=5;i++) {
        if(/ERROR/)                  # print previous buffer at ERROR
            print b[i]
        b[i]=b[i+1]
    }
}
/ERROR/,/(INFO|WARN|DEBUG|TRACE)/ {  # between markers arm the output flag
    f=5
}
f&&f--' file                         # keeps negative valued flags out
```

Comment: A range expression will always pasta-fy... :-)

Comment: In Mel Gibson's voice: [_I'm hungry, I'm going to get something to eat_](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SVl8tJrSaio) :|

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed & nl):

```
nl -s': ' -w1 file |
sed -En ':a;N;s/\n/&/5;Ta
         /\n([0-9]+: ERROR[^\n]*)$/{
         s//\n**\1/;:b;p;n;/^[0-9]+: INFO/!bb;s/$/**/;:c;tc;N;s/\n/&/5;Tc;p;d};D'
```

Prepend line numbers using a `:` and space as a separator using the `nl` command and pipe the results into `sed`.

Fetch 5 lines into the pattern space and then check the sixth for the starting pattern.

If the sixth line does not contain the starting pattern, remove the first line, append another to the pattern space and repeat.

If the sixth line does contain the starting pattern, insert `**` before the line number of that line, print/clear the pattern space, continue printing all lines until the ending pattern is matched.

Once the ending pattern is matched, prepend `**` to end of that line, fetch and append 5 further lines and print the result.

The pattern space is cleared and the normal sed cycle is then resumed and the process repeated.